# Syntax error: Expected end of input but got keyword LEFT at [14:1]

Tags: google-bigquery

Can somebody tell me why i get an error message about Left Join? Thanks!

```
SELECT
  PROD_ID,
  OUTLET_ID,
  ORDER_NO,
  DATE_ID_DLVRY,
  ORDER_QTY,
  ORDER_QTY_BOOKED,
  ORDER_POS_STATUS
FROM
  `v135-5203-bq-td-sync.epviews.v_orders` 
WHERE
  DATE_ID BETWEEN "2021-10-01"
  AND "2021-10-03"  
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT
    OUTLET_ID,
    PROD_ID,
    ORD_NO,
    BOOKING_DATE_ID,
    SUM(PURCH_QTY),
    DATE_ID
  FROM
    `v135-5203-bq-td-sync.epviews.v_purch` )
ON
  `v135-5203-bq-td-sync.epviews.v_orders`.DATE_ID = `v135-5203-bq-td-sync.epviews.v_purch`.DATE_ID
WHERE
  DATE_ID BETWEEN "2021-10-01"
  AND "2021-10-03"
```

Comment: you might want to **FROM (SELECT * FROM v135-5203-bq-td-sync.epviews.v_orders WHERE DATE_ID BETWEEN "2021-10-01" AND "2021-10-03")**  .

Answer (score 1):

You could try the code below. I moved the `WHERE` clause inside `JOIN` to avoid filtering unnecessary fields in the query. Also I removed the `SELECT` statement inside the `LEFT JOIN` statement since it will cause an unexpected `SELECT` statement error. (I just modified the table name for simplicity sake of my replication)

**Working Query:**

```
SELECT
  PROD_ID,
  OUTLET_ID,
  ORDER_NO,
  DATE_ID_DLVRY,
  ORDER_QTY,
  ORDER_QTY_BOOKED,
  ORDER_POS_STATUS
FROM
  v_orders
LEFT JOIN 
   v_purch 
ON
  v_orders.date_id = v_purch.date_id
WHERE
  v_purch.date_id BETWEEN "2021-10-01"
  AND "2021-10-03"
```